# MVC Image Handling using WebImage and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, webimage

In a view, I have the following `fieldset` which displays images, in thumbnail type form, associated with a particular item:

```
<fieldset style="position:absolute; top:113px; left: 1050px; width: 300px;">
    <legend>Photos</legend>

    <div>
        <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage1")" alt="" />
        <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage2")" alt="" />     
        <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage2")" alt="" />     
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

In my controller, I have the following code:

```
public void GetImage1()
{
    BicycleSellerListing bicyclesellerlisting = db.BicycleSellerListing.Find(1023);

    WebImage wbImage = new WebImage(bicyclesellerlisting.ImageList.First().Image);
    wbImage.Resize(100, 100);
    wbImage.FileName = "Item.jpg";
    wbImage.Write();
}
```

All of this works fine. I am fairly new to MVC, HTML and JavaScript, and don't know how to do the following.  What I would like to do is to allow the user to click on an image and have another View load where I display the full size of the image in that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to get from this. Do you want it to display the image alone on a new page or show the full image on the same page using AJAX?

If it's the latter, you might want to look into using partial views.

Comment: In my post I said, "...and have another View load where I display the full size of the image in that view." So, new page.

Comment: Well that's pretty easy then, just have another action that takes you to the full image. You can just use <a href="@Url.Action(...)"><img ... /></a>